# select between to dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in my db `admission`

```
     id      pa_name   health_no     date_adm       
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      1      John        1500         20/01/2010          
      2      Jorge       1800         28/01/2011          
      3      Sara        1000         09/04/2012          
      4      John        1500         11/01/2013          
      5      John        1500         15/01/2015          
      6      Sara        1000         18/01/2016
```

I tried this query, but it gives the wrong result.

```
SELECT * FROM admission
WHERE admission.date_adm IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT date_adm FROM admission
    WHERE date_adm NOT BETWEEN
        timestamp(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 year))
        AND
        timestamp(NOW())
)
```

My question is do I need a query to select `health_no records` for patients not admitted through last 5 years, excluding any `health_no`, if patient was admitted during the last 5 years.

Results should be like this:

```
pa_name     health_no
--------   ----------
Sara        1000  
----------------------
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the question?  .. you have error? wrong result .. ? show your actual result too .. and whici data type is date_adm ?

Comment: date_adm type : datetime

Comment: the actual results : the above query shows all records  between current date and last  5 years ; while  i  need only health_no of patient who never admitted during last 5  years

Comment: `20/01/2010` that isn't date time, it's varchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your date_adm is a date data type you could check for healt_no not in the ones in last 5 years

```
SELECT * 
from admission WHERE admission.health_no  NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT  health_no      
  from admission 
  WHERE date_adm BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 year) AND NOW()
)
```

Comment: MySQL stores a date type as YYYY-mm-dd and they're using almost the opposite as shown in their graphic. They probably thinks this works or they didn't show us the actuals.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  Hi  Fred-ii- . all right? I have explicitly asked for the type of data for this reason. OP will eventually become alive with some clarification and in case I provide the conversion best suited to its needs.

Comment: @scaisEdge The question is unclear in regards to the values posted for the `date_adm` column. The Q&A is misleading (for future readers).